# IPN simulator error: Cannot GET /webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator/

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, simulator

I'm having problems with the IPN simulator here:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator/

Sometimes a page is displayed with the error:
Cannot GET /webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator/

Sometimes it displays the page as expected, but on submitting the form the page just reloads. No message that ipn was sent, just as if the page was opened for the first time.

I have used this ipn simulator page before (a few months ago) and it was working fine. I was receiving ipn data, sending it back, and getting the confirmation.

Here is the first part of the ipn handler code. It just saves the ipn data before sending it back to have Paypal verify it. However, this is never executed, since the ipn data is never sent from the simulator. The error:
"Cannot GET /webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator/" is displayed when loading the ipn simulator page, before attempting to send anything.

```
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Log initial ipn data, before verification
error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Pre validation ipn data:  ".PHP_EOL.$raw_post_data. PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
```

Update: As of Feb 8 2016, 7:49 pm GMT, it is currently working.

Update: Never mind, it worked once, and quit again with same error as in question title.

Comment: post your code, sounds like a redirect is happening for some reason causing the GET error

Comment: Thanks David, I updated the question with code.